# How to get 100% code coverage in Python?

Tags: python, tdd, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-coverage

**learning.py**

```
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def addition(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**test_learning.py**

```
import unittest

from learning import *

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_multiply(self):
        self.assertEqual( multiply(3,4), 12)

    def test_addition(self):
        self.assertEqual( addition(5,10), 15)       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**50% code coverage**

Although both methods have been tested, the code coverage is 50%

```
C:\>coverage run learning.py test_learning.py

C:\>coverage report

Name       Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------
learning       4      2    50%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coverage command you want is:

```
coverage run test_learning.py
```

What you're doing is running `learning.py` with the argument `test_learning.py`, which only executes the 2 `def` statements and never runs the tests (or executes the contents of the 2 defined functions).

Comment: It works now `TOTAL              13      0   100%` Thank you.